# 01010003 keyboard not detected while holding shift to access grub

Tags: command-line, grub2, fsck

**Hello to whoever reading this!**

so my problem is that I can't do a filesystem check in ubuntu cuz I cannot access the grub menu!

whenever I hold shift while booting up it gives this error "01010003 keyboard not detected!"

I have tried updating grub with the terminal but it is still not fixed...

does anyone know the solution? I would be thankful if you help me!

Comment: Is your keyboard plugged directly into the motherboard in the back of the computer?

Comment: Who or what issues the `keyboard not detected`? The firmware of the machine itself? Then your firmware may 'see' a keyboard with a stuck key and think it's broken. Wait until AFTER the firmware initialized the keyboard and then press shift. (Yes, that may take a few tries.) Also, study the options in `/etc/default/grub`: there is an option `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` that may help you by **always** showing the menu while waiting for the timeout. Don't forget `sudo update-grub` after each edit of `/etc/default/grub`.